# Установить дефолтную дату Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Как установить дефолтную (текущую) дату для поля `article_date` ?

Есть поле в бд `article_date = models.DateTimeField()` как устанвсить при добавлении статьи сюда текущую дату на момент её добавления?

Пробовал так:

```
article_date = models.DateTimeField(default=lambda x=None: datetime.now())
```

Оно работает, но миграцию провести не пускает...

Возможно можно передать значение в поле при создании статьи?

Функция:

```
def add_art(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, Django [не передаёт никаких аргументов](https://github.com/django/django/blob/60e52a047e55bc4cd5a93a8bd4d07baed27e9a22/django/db/backends/base/schema.py#L212-L213) в функцию `default`, соответственно `x=None` совершенно необязателен:

```
article_date = models.DateTimeField(default=lambda: datetime.now())
```

Во-вторых, лямбды не дружат с миграциями, а чтобы подружиться, нужно создать нормальную функцию, у которой будет нормальная переменная:

```
def default_datetime(): return datetime.now()

class ВашаМодель(models.Model):
    article_date = models.DateTimeField(default=default_datetime)
```

Так уже должно работать.

В-третьих, в функции без аргументов, которая вызывает другую функцию без аргументов, нет никакого смысла, и можно просто прописать в `default` эту самую функцию:

```
article_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

В-четвёртых, если вы ходите проставить дату создания статьи, то это в DateTimeField уже встроено.

То есть **готовый код может выглядеть так**:

```
article_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Тогда при создании объекта в этом поле будет автоматически проставляться текущая дата.

[Документация по auto_now_add](https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/models/fields.html#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)

Comment: Спасибо большое.